# Count directory and exclude dir

Tags: count, find

I have the fallowing command to count all image in folder "find . -type f | sed -e 's/.*.//' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | grep -Ei '(tif| jpg| jpep| gif)$'" What do I need to add to it to have exclude a directory?

Comment: Add a `-not -path YOUR_EXCLUDE_DIR` clause to it.

Comment: where do you add in the command

Comment: `find . -type f -not -path YOUR_EXCLUDE_DIR ...`

Comment: would this be how I exclude folder1 with in the root directory I am using find command on? find . -type f -not - /folder1 | sed -e 's/.*.//' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | grep -Ei '(tif| jpg| jpep| gif)$'

Comment: `find . -type f -not -path "./folder1/*" ...`

Comment: Can I add this after "| sed -e 's/.*.//' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | grep -Ei '(tif| jpg| jpep| gif)$'" to count by file type. find . -type f -not -path "./folder1/*" | sed -e 's/.*.//' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | grep -Ei '(tif| jpg| jpep| gif)$'